# Upon successful login page is still showing 403 forbidden in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

So, ive implememented this basic spring security in my website. Upon login with the correct credentials on a private route it is still showing 403 forbidden.

It is taking the correct credentials as on entering the wrong one the default spring security login page shows bad credentials.

SpringSecurityConfig

```
package com.naha.crimereportingsystem;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    // Authentication
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    // Authorization
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/police").hasRole("POLICE")
            .antMatchers("/users")
            .hasRole("USER").antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin().and().httpBasic();

        http.logout();

        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

User Model

```
package com.naha.crimereportingsystem.user;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean active = true;
    private String roles = "USER";

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(String roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

}
```

UserRepository used, as im using Spring JPA

```
package com.naha.crimereportingsystem.user;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

MyUserDetails

```
package com.naha.crimereportingsystem.user;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public MyUserDetails(User user) {
        this.userName = user.getUsername();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.active = user.isActive();
        this.authorities = Arrays.stream(user.getRoles().split(",")).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return userName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return active;
    }
}
```

MyUserDetailsSerivce

```
package com.naha.crimereportingsystem.user;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public MyUserDetails(User user) {
        this.userName = user.getUsername();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.active = user.isActive();
        this.authorities = Arrays.stream(user.getRoles().split(",")).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return userName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return active;
    }
}
```

Users controller

```
@GetMapping("/users")
    public String UserRoute() {
        return "users";
    }
```

Lastly, the database
[image: DB image]

Comment: `hasRole` prefixes the passed in role with `ROLE_` so in yur case it checks if the user has the authority `ROLE_USER` which it doesn't as it has `USER`. Either prefix the roles of the user or use `hasAuthority` instead of `hasRole`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the following line in your `User` class :

```
private String roles = "USER";
```

With :

```
private String roles = "ROLE_USER";
```

Comment: Yes it worked thanks!
Also can you tell me that why do we need to have two model class, User and MyUserDetails to implement spring security, i saw this from an online tutorial. Is this the normal convention or this guy did it differently?

Comment: Yon don’t need to, only an implementation of UserDetails is mandatory to handle Spring Security authentication with Database

Comment: So i can have my User class directly implement User details and itll work just fine?